# Remove Duplicate List Dictionary based on the Designations

Tags: python

Below list dict, if we have duplicate names then need to get the dict which is having the designation.If its single name then need to get the dict which does'nt have designation

```
lst = [{'desig': '', 'name': 'William'}, {'desig': 'Chairman of the Board', 'name': 'William'}, {'desig': '', 'name': 'English'}, {'desig': 'Director', 'name': 'English'}, {'desig': '', 'name': 'Charles '}]
```

My output should be like below.

```
lst = [{'desig': 'Chairman of the Board', 'name': 'William'}, {'desig': 'Director', 'name': 'English'}, {'desig': '', 'name': 'Charles '}]
```

Comment: what did you try yourself?

Comment: What do you do if there are duplicates, both with non-null designations? `[{'desig': 'Chairman of the Board', 'name': 'William'}, {'desig': 'Director', 'name': 'William'}]`

Comment: Ben, I'm assuming from the question that for whatever reason, that will never occur.

Comment: No chance for both not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should solve your problem. Note that if the names are not exactly the same they will be counted as different names. In your original post, the second item has the name 'William' whilst the first has the name 'William ' which has a space after the m!!!

```
data = [{'desig': '', 'name': 'William'}, {'desig': 'Chairman of the Board', 'name': 'William'},
        {'desig': '', 'name': 'English'}, {'desig': 'Director', 'name': 'English'},
        {'desig': '', 'name': 'Charles '}]

cleaned_data = []
names_added = []
for entry in data:
    if entry['name'] in names_added:
        if entry['desig'] != '':  # the != '' is actually not necessary, but included for clarity
            i = names_added.index(entry['name'])
            cleaned_data[i]=entry
    else:
        cleaned_data.append(entry)
        names_added.append(entry['name'])

print(cleaned_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [{'desig': '', 'name': 'William'}, {'desig': 'Chairman of the Board', 'name': 'William'}, {'desig': '', 'name': 'English'}, {'desig': 'Director', 'name': 'English'}, {'desig': '', 'name': 'Charles '}]
d = defaultdict(list)
for i in lst:
    d[i['name']].append(i['desig'])
l = [{'desig': sorted(v)[-1], 'name': k}  for k, v in d.items()]

print(l)
```

Prints:

```
[{'desig': 'Chairman of the Board', 'name': 'William'}, {'desig': 'Director', 'name': 'English'}, {'desig': '', 'name': 'Charles '}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> lst = [{'desig': '', 'name': 'William'}, {'desig': 'Chairman of the Board', 'name': 'William'}, {'desig': '', 'name': 'English'}, {'desig': 'Director', 'name': 'English'}, {'desig': '', 'name': 'Charles '}]
>>> names=set()
>>> list(dict(names.add(d['name']) or (d['name'],d) for d in lst if not d['name'] in names or d['desig']).values())
[{'desig': 'Chairman of the Board', 'name': 'William'}, {'desig': 'Director', 'name': 'English'}, {'desig': '', 'name': 'Charles '}]
```